# eclipse not working after mousefeed plugin installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just installed Mousefeed plugin in my eclipse Juno. I was unaware that the plugin doesnot work for eclipse juno. Now the mouse click are unresponsive and I can only use shortcut keys. How do I uninstall the plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to uninstall plugin without using the mouse:

1. Ctrl+3
2. type "about"
3. select (with cursors and enter) menus - about eclipse
4. installation details
5. choose & uninstall plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure which shortcuts to use in Eclipse now, the easiest workaround is probably to shutdown eclipse and to delete the plugin on disk. Eclipse will then start without the plugin the next time.

The plugin should be at `<eclipse directory>\plugins\com.mousefeed_1.0.0.jar`. If not (depending on your OS and kind of installation), search only for a file containing "mousefeed" in the name and ending with ".jar".